# Restoring production gae data to the dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone have a solution to restore production gae data to a dev server for testing?  The Bulkuploader tool does not cater for models with Blob Properties.  Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulkloader works fine with blob properties, as long as you either use the `--dump` / `--restore` syntax, which doesn't require interpreting your models, or you take care to encode and decode blobs in the output format - for instance, by using base64.

Comment: Nick, thanks.  Can you please point me to documentation where --dump and --restore syntax is described?   I was looking at appcfg.py commandline options and could not find them there.

Comment: @Yasser http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data

Comment: they dont have dump and restore.  I am assuming download_data and upload_data are the equivalents. Right?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the syntax has changed a bit since I last looked.